# Pass Values to One2many From Transient model - odoo 13 (wrong Value Error)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, odoo-11, odoo-12, odoo-13

Model:

```
 class AjaxTimesheet(models.Model):

    _name = "ajax.timesheet" 

timesheet_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='ajax.timesheet',string='Timesheet', compute='_compute_timesheet_id')

 @api.depends('created_by')
    def _compute_timesheet_id(self):
        # Compute Timesheet Id for given Timesheet
        for rec in self:
            rec.timesheet_id = rec._origin.id
```

TransientModel:

```
 class TimesheetData(models.TransientModel):
        _name = "timesheet.data"
        _description = "Timesheet Data" 

time_task_ids = fields.One2many('ajax.timesheet','timesheet_id',string='Timesheet')



  @api.onchange('created_by','created_date')
            def on_change_created_by(self):

                # list the task in timesheet based on user
                task_ids = self.env['prj.task'].search([('task_assigned_to','=',self.created_by.id),
                                                        ('state','=','ongoing'),('child_ids','=',False)])
                task_list = []
                for task in task_ids:
                    timesheet = self.env['timesheet.timesheet'].search([('task_ids', '=', task.id)])
                    tot_time = 0
                    for i in timesheet:
                        tot_time += i.duration
                    tot_duration = task.task_planned_hours - tot_time
                    vals = {
                        'task_ids': task.id,
                        'created_date': self.created_date,
                        'created_by': self.created_by.id,
                        'prj_project_id':task.prj_project_id.id,
                        'planned_hour': task.task_planned_hours,
                        'task_deadline_date': task.task_deadline_date,
                        'balance_hour': tot_duration,
                        'ref_parent_id':  task.task_assigned_to.parent_id.id,
                    }
                    task_list.append((0, 0, vals))
                self.time_task_ids = task_list
```

Error in this line: self.time_task_ids = task_list
ValueError: Wrong value for ajax.timesheet.timesheet_id: timesheet.data(,)

timesheet.data(,) - I guess object ID should be ajax.timesheet model's but here it is from timesheet.data(,) that is why the error is as wrong value. Any solution to FIX this Error.

Error:
Odoo Server Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 664, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 345, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/service/model.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 338, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 910, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 510, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1320, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1312, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/api.py", line 395, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/api.py", line 382, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/models.py", line 6056, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/models.py", line 5857, in _onchange_eval
    method_res = method(self)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/addons/ajax_timesheet/wizard/wizard_timesheet.py", line 98, in on_change_created_by
    self.time_task_ids = task_list
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 1068, in __set__
    self.write(new_records, value)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 2758, in write
    return self.write_batch([(records, value)])
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 2782, in write_batch
    return self.write_new(records_commands_list)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 3002, in write_new
    line[inverse] = record
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/models.py", line 5598, in __setitem__
    return self._fields[key].__set__(self, value)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 1068, in __set__
    self.write(new_records, value)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 2467, in write
    cache_value = self.convert_to_cache(value, records)
  File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 2400, in convert_to_cache
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
ValueError: Wrong value for ajax.timesheet.timesheet_id: timesheet.data(<NewId 0x7f498243af98>,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this:

```
new_record = self.env['ajax.timesheet'].create({
 //create record fields;
})

self.env.cr.commit()
task_list.append(new_record.id)

self.update({
    'time_task_ids': (6, 0, task_list)
})
self.env.cr.commit()
```

Because you are updating the value of this field **`@api.onchange`**. So when ever you want to change the data of model field you have to use update or write method according to your scenarios.

And this is the way how to enter value

> (0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created
>   with the given values dictionary
>
> (1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write
>   *values* on it)
>
> (2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id =
>   ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and
>   the link to it as well)
>
> (3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID
>   (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete
>   the target object itself)
>
> (4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a
>   relationship)
>
> (5)                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked
>   records)
>
> (6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5)
>   then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)

Comment: value = self._data[field][record._ids[0]]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'  @adam

Comment: You did as i said?

Comment: No changes brother

Comment: yestask_list.append((0, 0, vals))
        self.update({
            'time_task_ids': [[6, 0, task_list]]
        })
        self.env.cr.commit()

Comment: listen here you are using one2many field which is with some model, so you have to create values in that model and append created ids in list.

Comment: yes tried pass values using create method from transient model but Error came as timesheet.data(56,) like this

Comment: I am passing values to One2many field and this works fine in odoo 10

Comment: cant pass list having <newId -

Comment: value = self._data[field][record._ids[0]] TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'  this is what i got

Comment: pass value like this (6, 0, [task_list])

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: hahaha then go with (6, 0, task_list) because task_list is already a list

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: [(0, 0, {'task_ids': 20, 'created_date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 26), 'created_by': 6, 'prj_project_id': 21, 'planned_hour': 8.0, 'task_deadline_date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 29), 'balance_hour': 8.0, 'ref_parent_id': 3}), (0, 0, {'task_ids': 18, 'created_date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 26), 'created_by': 6, 'prj_project_id': 21, 'planned_hour': 8.0, 'task_deadline_date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 29), 'balance_hour': 8.0, 'ref_parent_id': 3})]     when i print task list

Comment: How? and what do u mean?

Comment: Edit your question, because i am getting vibes that you are not doing as i said :P

Comment: Thing is One2many and many2one both related to same model. But One2many in Transient model we are passing values from Transient model by appending values to list and assign to One2Many getting Error in ASSIGNMENT with one2Many to list

Comment: self.time_task_ids = task_list  (in this line)

Comment: give me your maild id i ll send u a pics

Comment: I am stuck in this give me a solution brother

Comment: ValueError: Wrong value for ajax.timesheet.timesheet_id: timesheet.data(86,)

Comment: straussadam55@gmail.com

Comment: Check Your mail brother